# Problema con el resultado esperado de una función invocada en javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo es codigo html:

```
<table>
<?php
if(is_array($filas))
{
    $imagen = "";

    foreach($filas as $fila)
    {
        $asientos = $fila["asientos"];
?>
      <tr>
      <td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $fila["fila"]; ?></td>
      <?php
        for($i = 1; $i <= $asientos; $i++)
        {
         $asiento = $fila["fila"].$i;

         if(Fila::comprobarAsiento($asiento))
            $imagen = "v".$i;
         else
            $imagen = "d".$i;
      ?>
         <td><img id="<?php echo $asiento; ?>" src="img/<?php echo $imagen; ?>.png" 
           onMouseOver="seleccionarAsiento(this);"></td>
      <?php
        }
      ?>
      <td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $fila["fila"]; ?></td>
      </tr>
<?php       
    }
}
?>
</table>
```

Y tengo estas funciones en javascript:

```
function seleccionarAsiento(e)
{
    var idasiento = e.id;

    if(!comprobarAsiento(idasiento)) 
    {
     var num = idasiento.substr(1, idasiento.length - 1);
     e.src = "img/sa" + num + ".png"; 
    }
    else
     alert("Asiento ocupado");
} 

function comprobarAsiento(asiento)
{
    var xhttp;

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else
        xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200)
        {
            var data = xhttp.responseText;

            if(data == 1)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }   

    xhttp.open("POST", "includes/acciones/fila/comprobar.php");
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.send("asiento=" + asiento);
}
```

La aplicación web es de reservación de asientos, como ven cuando paso el mouse por una imagen se ejecuta el evento **onMouseOver** que a la vez este ejecuta un función llamada **seleccionarAsiento**, esta función invoca a otra función llamada **comprobarAsiento** la cual recibe como parámetro el asiento a comprobar, si esta función devuelve true quiere decir que el asiento está ocupado y si devuelve false quiere decir que el asiento está disponible, la pregunta aquí es por que la función **comprobarAsiento** me está devolviendo *undefined*??

---

A la función comprobarAsiento la agregue dos líneas y tampoco funciono

```
function comprobarAsiento(asiento)
{
    var xhttp;
    var estado;

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else
        xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200)
        {
            var data = xhttp.responseText;

            if(data == 1)
                estado = true;
            else
                estado = false;
        }
    }   

    xhttp.open("POST", "includes/acciones/fila/comprobar.php");
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.send("asiento=" + asiento);

    return estado;
}
```

Comment: básicamente porque no tienes una sentencia `return` en tu funcion comprobarAsiento

Comment: @LPZadkiel y que tendría que poner??

Comment: if(Fila::comprobarAsiento($asiento)) esta escrito en php y la funcion escrita en js :v

Comment: @Bryro y que tiene que ver que una función escrita en php se llame igual a otra función escrita en javascript??

Comment: Que php se ejecuta mucho antes de js y por ende no puedes validar con js algo escrito en php :v

Comment: tu problema es que estas pensando de forma sincrónica pero las llamadas a servidor son asíncronas, esto quiere decir que tu función `comprobarAsiento` termina antes de que haya llegado la respuesta desde el servidor así que los cambios de estados en tu html podrías hacerlos después de que llegue la información, podrías hacer lo siguiente, en la función `onmouseover` comprobar con servidor si esta ocupado y cuando llegue la respuesta (onreadystatechange) ejecutas el código para cambiar la visualización

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tu problema es que estas pensando de forma sincrónica pero las llamadas a servidor son asíncronas, esto quiere decir que tu función `comprobarAsiento` termina antes de que haya llegado la respuesta desde el servidor así que los cambios de estados en tu html podrías hacerlos después de que llegue la información, cambiando un poco tu código quedaría de esta forma:

```
        <table>
<?php
if(is_array($filas))
{
    $imagen = "";

    foreach($filas as $fila)
    {
        $asientos = $fila["asientos"];
?>
      <tr>
      <td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $fila["fila"]; ?></td>
      <?php
        for($i = 1; $i <= $asientos; $i++)
        {
         $asiento = $fila["fila"].$i;

         if(Fila::comprobarAsiento($asiento))
            $imagen = "v".$i;
         else
            $imagen = "d".$i;
      ?>
         <td><img id="<?php echo $asiento; ?>" src="img/<?php echo $imagen; ?>.png" 
           onMouseOver="seleccionarAsiento(this);"></td>
      <?php
        }
      ?>
      <td style="text-align: center;"><?php echo $fila["fila"]; ?></td>
      </tr>
<?php       
    }
}
?>
</table>
Y tengo estas funciones en javascript:

function seleccionarAsiento(e)
{
    var idasiento = e.id;


var xhttp;

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
        xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else
        xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200)
        {
            var data = xhttp.responseText;

            if(data == 1) {
                var num = idasiento.substr(1, idasiento.length - 1);
                e.src = "img/sa" + num + ".png";
           } else { alert("Asiento ocupado"); }
        }
    }   

    xhttp.open("POST", "includes/acciones/fila/comprobar.php");
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhttp.send("asiento=" + idasiento);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

la funcion es asyncrona por ello no esta retornando el valor tal y como lo comento LPZadkiel
puedes seguir esta respuesta dada en la version en ingles que utilizan promise
https://stackoverflow.com/a/30008115/10226928